# How to check particular ID in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need to check an ID whether is available in the DOM, before using the document.getElementById.

i.e. We have find() in jquery. Need to know the same in javascript

Please find the below example.

since dsp-store-name is not available in the DOM, its throwing the below exception in the console.

```
document.getElementById("dsp-store-name").innerHTML
```

> VM655:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
>       at :1:43
>   (anonymous) @ VM655:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only actual way is to select that element and verify if it exists.

```
var e = document.getElementById('dsp-store-name');
if(e){
   var eHTML = e.innerHTML;
   // rest of code. 
} else {
   // does not exist == 'null'
}
```

Comment: Yea, actually using document.querySelectorAll also solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

See if the result of the call is null *before* attempting to use the element:

```
var el = document.getElementById("dsp-store-name");
if (el != null)
   el.innerHTML = "hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

check document.getElementById("dsp-store-name") for the null value, if element is not present document.getElementById() will return null.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("dsp-store-names"));
console.log(document.getElementById("dsp-store-name"));
```

```html
<div id="dsp-store-name"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, got the answer. we can achieve it by document.querySelectorAll

Answer (score -1):

you can use this to check:-

```
if(document.getElementById("dsp-store-name") != null){
    var something=document.getElementById("dsp-store-name").innerHTML;
}
```